# MySQL UPDATE with JOIN unexpectedly updated every row in the table

Tags: mysql

I ran this query expecting it to update the security name and trading entity name for a specific symbol assignment, but instead it updated every record in both tables with the same name - time to restore from backup!

```
UPDATE 
    SymbolAssignments sa
       JOIN
    Securities s ON sa.SecurityId = sa.SecurityId
       JOIN
    TradingEntityNames en ON s.TradingEntityNameId = en.TradingEntityNameId
SET 
    s.Name = name,
    en.Name = name
WHERE 
    sa.SymbolAssignmentId = symbolAssignmentId;
```

Can anyone explain why the WHERE clause had no effect, and every row was updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid fault, this line

```
Securities s ON sa.SecurityId = sa.SecurityId
```

should have been

```
Securities s ON s.SecurityId = sa.SecurityId
```

Of course sa.SecurityId always equals sa.SecurityId, hence all records were updated. This is a bad gotcha, because i thought I was protected from wiping out all the data by ensuring the WHERE clause limits the scope. In fact for UPDATE or DELETE I always type the WHERE clause first. It's a good habit, but didn't save me this time.